# Is water recycling really necessary in space?

Tags: space, geology, water

Solar panels = energy

Mineral harvesting machines= materials

3D printers that print solar panels= infinite energy

So we got the energy part out of the way for space travel, just build more satelites following you around and providing energy.

oxygen= just build a plankton and algae farm for an endless source of oxygen.

But water, is it really necessary to recycle feces and urine as well as building machines that harvest humidity from the sweat and evaporation to turn it back into drinkable water?

or is water easily available on asteroids without the need to ever land on any planet or moon? Easily means, not having to travel years to find another source of water.

Comment: Having enough energy recycling water is quite simple, if distilling isn't good enough, then electrolyse it, separate hydrogen oxygen by cryogenic means, and purify history of that hydrogen by holy fire which also will make a barrier for any accidental contamination. Ecosystem also can be used for purification. Otherwise rocks are source of oxygen, gas giants and stars source of hydrogen - combine those two sources and you get water. In general recycling is easier and it can be bulletproof. I mean, what kind of a problem with water recycling do you see or interested about?

Comment: Some asteroids are water-rich, but most, especially in the inner Solar System, are dry. If you are not on a water rich asteroid, water recycling is your best option.

Comment: if they can purify water harvested from asteroids they can purify waste water.

Answer (score 8):

It's all a matter of time and efficiency: by recycling wastes you are using water and resources you already have available, while if you have to mine them somewhere you have to reach the place and do the whole processing. On top of that, you will have to do something with the wastes anyway.

And all the energy you will spare by recycling will be better used somewhere else. That you might have an abundant supply of energy (I would not say infinite) doesn't mean you can splurge and waste it by using it in a non efficient way.

Answer (score 6):

The big constraint in space is mass.  The heavier you are, the slower you accelerate and the longer it takes to get anywhere.  Additionally, there's a multiplier:  for every unit of payload mass, you need X units of fuel/reaction mass to reach a given delta-v.

If you don't recycle your water, that means you're carrying many times more water than you need, which means you're carrying many times more fuel, which makes everything slower and more expensive.

And really, what reason is there not to recycle your water?  Water gets recycled on Earth; wastewater evaporates up into the atmosphere, then falls as rain onto the land, where it is collected and drunk as fresh water.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is yes, any spaceship travelling for any substantial amount of time with humans on board would recycle their own own waste for water. The average recommended intake of water for adults daily lies between 2 and 3 liters, which comes out to about roughly 60 liters per month for EACH person. Long story short, humans need a lot of water. I don't know what kind of spaceship you have in mind, but it would be uneconomical for spaceships to be slugging around massive storage tanks of thousands of liters, unless you are onboard the spaceship equivalent of a containership  I guess.

Your ship could mine any asteroid it passes for water, but that would require equipment onboard for turning water ice coating an asteroid into drinkable water, which would require, you guessed it, a filtration system! so you have one on your ship anyway. If this would be your only way of getting water it would require charting a route around stooping at asteroids that may or may not have water ice, an extremely risky prospect if you can't detect the presence of water ice on it from large distances away and leaving you potentially stranded with no water to mine.

as a side note, filtration systems can easily recycle urine, but I have found no examples of feces being recycled for water. Also manufacturing components like solar panels would require a workshop, and not just a 3d printer, unless we are talking about sci-fi replicators that can print entire components ready for use.

Hope this answer helps!

Comment: I mean, there are 3D printers creating rockets and cars, houses and guns.... thought solar panels were actually the easier part.

Comment: @fivepercent solar panels, if you think photovoltaics, it is crystal cut in pieces, with doping elements which penetrate surface to a specific depth, etc. Printing crystal structure, won't be easy, I mean it waymuch harder than printing a sheet of metal as an example. But that 3d printing perception is not necessarly has some problems,  I mean fundamentaly, as there are other means of converting solar energy  in space(in space is important) which can be technologically much easier to produce and 3d printing perception may not be that far fro actual processes.

Comment: @fivepercent Just because it is a rectangle with no moving parts doesn't mean it's a dumb slab of material. It just means all the "moving parts" are so tiny you can't see them which makes it even more difficult to print. It's not like a pane of glass or a mirror. Your examples are pieces of material that sit there doing nothing. It's like comparing a hunk of rubber to a hunk of human tissue.

Comment: Feces does contain water, simple evaporating it out and filtering.  Think about a dehydrator for making beef jerky.  The warm air simply evaporates the moisture out of the meat and that water just goes into the air.  reclaim it from there.

Answer (score 4):

### Space is big.

Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space.

The distance from Earth to the Moon is greater than driving back and forth across the USA 58 times. The gaps between the planets and asteroids are even greater. That means it takes a long time to travel between them. As such, if you need to rely on solar power, a weak and slow power source, it's gonna take a very long time to travel between them. Months, years.

As such, you need to recycle your scarce resources, poo included.

Comment: I don't even like pulling over for gas when I drive by the station on the way home.

Comment: It's actually worse than pulling over for gas; imagine if you were driving along the highway, wanted to grab a bottle of water at a store you saw ahead, and then had to burn a quarter of your fuel in order to stop to pick up said water.

Comment: +1 for the H2G2 reference

Answer (score 1):

## Why recycle anything here on earth?

We have this ginormous sun, lots of coal, the ability to create nuclear reactors, and in your world's terms we have all the solar panels we could ever want<sup>1</sup>... in other words, we have all the energy we could ever need.<sup>2</sup> We have forests that recycle CO<sub>2</sub> and oceans full of water. The world is literally *full of space* where we can dump stuff we don't want. Don't let anyone fool you. We could place mountains of trash all over the place before it actually hurt the Earth.<sup>3</sup> Think about it, why on earth (ha...) do we recycle anything at all here on Earth?

1. Cost. The cost of moving (e.g.) trash to some out-of-the-way mountain in Arizona is higher than you can imagine. Likewise, tripping over to some waterlogged asteroid or taking the time to suck up and mix gas from a gas giant isn't at all free. You're still paying a cost in time (if nothing else). Of course time means more food being eaten, more things needing repair, trade schedules falling apart.... Time might be more precious than water.
2. Volume. You need enough water to do something plus a little more for emergencies (like realizing that waterlogged asteroid... isn't...). That's a **lot more** than you'd need if you recycled, and space ships ain't cheap. You need to build them and move them and keep them maintained... every cubic millimeter you don't need is one less chance of dying because something went wrong with it you can't fix.
3. Efficiency. Near-perfect recycling would let you go a long, long, long time before having to stop for water (or anything else). That's really useful if you're, you know, traversing galaxies or something like that.
4. Waste Sucks.<sup>4</sup> Humans can do one thing that Mother Nature cannot do: we can concentrate our activities into *ridiculously small spaces.* The result is that we create enormous waste. Yes, we could just pile it up and ignore it, but eventually you begin to smell it. By suggesting that you don't need to recycle water, you're basically admitting that what you're doing with it is, literally, pissing it away into space. This might be the very last thing on your average space traveler's mind, but a fair amount of the urine dumped overboard by the Apollo moon missions... *is still up there orbiting....*<sup>5</sup> There's a reason, my friend, that trains don't let you use the "facilities" in the station.

And then there's the answer to your question...

5. Because water really isn't just anywhere. Even here in our own solar system, you'd be traipsing all over the place to gain access to water. Yes, [we've found asteroids with water](https://www.space.com/water-rich-asteroids-space-exploration-fuel.html), but when you read that data with a business eye, you see things like "320,000 Olympic-sized swimming pools" and where the eager writer of the article saw infinite possibility, what your business eye saw was ***"that's an incredibly limited resource."*** (BTW, go reread #3 and replace "traversing galaxies" with "traveling between stars." Don't know how many ice-laden asteroids exist in the interplanetary void....) Remember, there's nothing *replacing* the water in those asteroids and there is *not* an infinite number of asteroids. Once the water in them is gone, you have a problem.

**To be fair, it's your world...**

What you do have is enough evidence to justify creating a world rule that states, "there's plenty of water out there that would make it possible to never pay to transition through a gravity well for more water." And I think that's a great idea!

But the engineer in me says, "you'll never have a good reason not to recycle."

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *There's an idea here that's rubbing my sense of fair play wrong. The idea that you can build a solar panel for less energy than the solar panel can produce implies a kind of perpetual-motion machine. The idea seems to violate the laws of thermodynamics. Maybe I'm wrong (and it's not important to the question anyhoo), but I'm kinda suspecting there's more handwaving in that condition than the OP thinks.*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *So long as we get the activists out of the way. They may actually be right, but so long as we need infinite energy, they're in the way. Read on, McDuff... my answer is all about priorities.*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *This is a pet peeve of mine. Hurt the Earth? Really? The Earth and its ability to sustain life has survived ice ages, hot spells, fire storms, solar flares, meteor impacts (one that we think created the Moon for crying out loud!)... Honestly! The Earth can handle anything and everything humanity can throw at it and come back strong and shining. What we're really trying to save is humanity's ridiculously rotund rear end. Anyone who tells you otherwise is trying to sell you something.*</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> *I know, I just got done making fun of activists. They're not* wrong, *they just tend to cause as many problems as they solve because they're over-focused on their issues. But one thing they're not wrong about, waste sucks.*</sub>

<sub><sup>5</sup> *If you're about to point out that the solar wind probably atomized those droplets a long time ago... you're probably right. But that doesn't make me wrong. You just wait until you're on approach to space dock and someone's "number two" takes out your navigational array. Yeah. Then you'll remember this footnote, tear your shirt and scream, "Why? Why didn't I listen to @JoinJBHonCodidact? Why?" Trust me.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**For accute life support, burn hydrogen**

Depends how much water you need and your level of technology. Suppose you're out of  recycled water for some reason and your crew gets really thirsty: you already have the oxigen. When there is a hydrogen source near, like a star, or [MPDT ion motor fuel](https://www.appliedimage.com/product/o93064-2/), you could burn the hydrogen to yield fresh water.

Other answers indicate the obvious source.. I agree, recycling is easier / less expensive.. but it will require buffers.. and buffers can get lost, or contaminated. Maybe an O2+H2 water generator must be considered as a device to use only in emergency circumstances ? Especially when it would cost fuel..

Comment: Solar winds also contain trace amounts of ionized O in addition to ionized H and free electrons.  I've wondered how much water could be continuously produced from capturing say 1 square km of these particles and combining them.  Assuming that's practically feasible.

Comment: The closer you can put your collector near the star, the more hydrogen yield you will have. With proper shielding and propulsion, you're able to mine hydrogen from the atmosphere of a near gas giant.

Answer (score 0):

You might think about the fact that you (almost certainly) inhabit a spaceship (AKA "Earth") which recycles its air & water - and pretty much everything else, in the long term.

Water, and other consumables such as air and food, has mass and requires storage containers which also have mass.  You need fuel to lift this mass off Earth (or wherever), and if you're going somewhere instead of just living in orbit, you need fuel to accelerate and decelerate that mass.  Oh, and you need more fuel to accelerate the mass of the fuel you need...  See "rocket equation": tps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

So at some point, it makes more sense to start recycling stuff rather than shipping it in.  The ISS recycles most of its water, and I think quite a bit of its oxygen.  Longer duration missions, and ones further from a resupply source, would of course want to recycle more, even to the point of growing food.

The other side of this is what happens to all that waste if you don't recycle it?  Take humidity from breathing & perspiration: if you just let it build up, you soon have 100% humidity.  Water will condense on any cool surface, perhaps shorting out electic wires, or causing corrosion.  All that other stuff: do you just let it build up, or pay to have it shipped back to Earth?